# GroupBy header row is missing in the angular slickgrid?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

In my case scenario, I have multiple slickgrids in one layout.

In that layout, based on some condition show and hide the slickgrid.

For that slickgrid hiding time, other slickgrid presented groupBy header rows are missing.

Image:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<div id="demo-container" class="container-fluid">
  <h2>
    {{title}}
    <span class="float-end">
      <a style="font-size: 18px"
         target="_blank"
         href="https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/examples/grid-draggrouping.component.ts">
        <span class="fa fa-link"></span> code
      </a>
    </span>
  </h2>
  <div class="subtitle" [innerHTML]="subTitle"></div>

  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs" data-test="add-500-rows-btn" (click)="enableFlag()">
          Hide Slickgrid
        </button>
        <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="add-500-rows-btn" (click)="loadData(500)">
          500 rows
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="add-50k-rows-btn" (click)="loadData(50000)">
          50k rows
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="clear-grouping-btn"
                (click)="clearGroupsAndSelects()">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Clear grouping
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="collapse-all-btn" (click)="collapseAllGroups()">
          <i class="fa fa-compress"></i> Collapse all groups
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="expand-all-btn" (click)="expandAllGroups()">
          <i class="fa fa-expand"></i> Expand all groups
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" (click)="toggleDraggableGroupingRow()">
          Toggle Draggable Grouping Row
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" (click)="exportToExcel()">
          <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o text-success"></i> Export to Excel
        </button> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="group-duration-sort-value-btn"
                (click)="groupByDurationOrderByCount(false)">
          Group by duration &amp; sort groups by value
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="group-duration-sort-count-btn"
                (click)="groupByDurationOrderByCount(true)">
          Group by duration &amp; sort groups by count
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="group-duration-effort-btn"
                (click)="groupByDurationEffortDriven()">
          Group by Duration &amp; then Effort-Driven
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="set-dynamic-filter"
                (click)="setFiltersDynamically()">
          Set Filters Dynamically
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" data-test="set-dynamic-sorting"
                (click)="setSortingDynamically()">
          Set Sorting Dynamically
        </button>
      </div>
    </div> -->
    <!-- <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="field1" class="col-sm-3 mb-2">Group by field(s)</label>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3"
                 *ngFor="let groupField of selectedGroupingFields; let i = index; trackBy: selectTrackByFn">
              <select class="form-select" name="groupField{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupingFields[i]"
                      (ngModelChange)="groupByFieldName($event, i)">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option [ngValue]="field.id" *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> -->
  </form>
  <div class="row mt-1 mb-1">
    <hr />
  </div>

  <angular-slickgrid gridId="grid19"
                     [dataset]="dataset"
                     [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                     [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                     (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event.detail)">
  </angular-slickgrid>
  <angular-slickgrid *ngIf="hideSlickgrid" gridId="grid18"
  [dataset]="dataset0"
  [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions0"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions0"
  (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event.detail)">
</angular-slickgrid>
</div>
```

**TS code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ExcelExportService } from '@slickgrid-universal/excel-export';
import { TextExportService } from '@slickgrid-universal/text-export';

import {
  AngularGridInstance,
  Aggregators,
  Column,
  DelimiterType,
  FieldType,
  FileType,
  Filters,
  Formatters,
  GridOption,
  Grouping,
  GroupingGetterFunction,
  GroupTotalFormatters,
  SortDirectionNumber,
  SortComparers,
} from './../modules/angular-slickgrid';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './grid-draggrouping.component.html'
})
export class GridDraggableGroupingComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Example 19: Draggable Grouping & Aggregators';
  subTitle = `
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Grouping-&-Aggregators" target="_blank">Wiki docs</a></li>
        <li>This example shows 3 ways of grouping</li>
        <ol>
          <li>Drag any Column Header on the top placeholder to group by that column (support moti-columns grouping by adding more columns to the drop area).</li>
          <li>Use buttons and defined functions to group by wichever field you want</li>
          <li>Use the Select dropdown to group, the position of the Selects represent the grouping level</li>
        </ol>
        <li>Fully dynamic and interactive multi-level grouping with filtering and aggregates ovor 50'000 items</li>
        <li>Each grouping level can have its own aggregates (over child rows, child groups, or all descendant rows)..</li>
        <li>Use "Aggregators" and "GroupTotalFormatters" directly from Angular-Slickgrid</li>
      </ul>
    `;

  angularGrid!: AngularGridInstance;
  columnDefinitions!: Column[];
  dataset!: any[];
  dataviewObj: any;
  draggableGroupingPlugin: any;
  durationOrderByCount = false;
  gridObj: any;
  gridOptions!: GridOption;
  processing = false;
  selectedGroupingFields: Array<string | GroupingGetterFunction> = ['', '', ''];
  excelExportService = new ExcelExportService();
  textExportService = new TextExportService();
  columnDefinitions0!: Column[];
  dataset0!: any[];
  gridOptions0!: GridOption;
  public hideSlickgrid:boolean=true;

  constructor() {
    // define the grid options & columns and then create the grid itself
    this.loadData(500);
    this.defineGrid();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // populate the dataset once the grid is ready
    this.defineGrid();
  }

  angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
    this.angularGrid = angularGrid;
    this.gridObj = angularGrid.slickGrid; // grid object
    this.dataviewObj = angularGrid.dataView;
  }

  /* Define grid Options and Columns */
  defineGrid() {
    this.columnDefinitions = [
      {
        id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title',
        width: 70, minWidth: 50,
        cssClass: 'cell-title',
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'title',
          formatter: (g) => `Title: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'duration', name: 'Duration', field: 'duration',
        width: 70,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.slider, operator: '>=' },
        type: FieldType.number,
        groupTotalsFormatter: GroupTotalFormatters.sumTotals,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'duration',
          formatter: (g) => `Duration: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          comparer: (a, b) => {
            return this.durationOrderByCount ? (a.count - b.count) : SortComparers.numeric(a.value, b.value, SortDirectionNumber.asc);
          },
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'percentComplete', name: '% Complete', field: 'percentComplete',
        minWidth: 70, width: 90,
        formatter: Formatters.percentCompleteBar,
        type: FieldType.number,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.compoundSlider },
        sortable: true,
        groupTotalsFormatter: GroupTotalFormatters.avgTotalsPercentage,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'percentComplete',
          formatter: (g) => `% Complete: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        },
        params: { groupFormatterPrefix: '<i>Avg</i>: ' }
      },
      {
        id: 'start', name: 'Start', field: 'start', minWidth: 60,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.compoundDate },
        formatter: Formatters.dateIso,
        type: FieldType.dateUtc,
        outputType: FieldType.dateIso,
        exportWithFormatter: true,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'start',
          formatter: (g) => `Start: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'finish', name: 'Finish', field: 'finish',
        minWidth: 60,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.compoundDate },
        formatter: Formatters.dateIso,
        type: FieldType.dateUtc,
        outputType: FieldType.dateIso,
        exportWithFormatter: true,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'finish',
          formatter: (g) => `Finish: ${g.value} <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'cost', name: 'Cost', field: 'cost',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.compoundInput },
        formatter: Formatters.dollar,
        groupTotalsFormatter: GroupTotalFormatters.sumTotalsDollar,
        type: FieldType.number,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'cost',
          formatter: (g) => `Cost: ${g.value} <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: true,
          collapsed: true
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'effortDriven', name: 'Effort-Driven', field: 'effortDriven',
        width: 80, minWidth: 20, maxWidth: 100,
        cssClass: 'cell-effort-driven',
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: {
          collection: [{ value: '', label: '' }, { value: true, label: 'True' }, { value: false, label: 'False' }],
          model: Filters.singleSelect
        },
        formatter: Formatters.checkmark,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'effortDriven',
          formatter: (g) => `Effort-Driven: ${g.value ? 'True' : 'False'} <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          collapsed: false
        }
      }
    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
      autoResize: {
        container: '#demo-container',
        rightPadding: 10
      },
      enableDraggableGrouping: true,
      createPreHeaderPanel: true,
      showPreHeaderPanel: true,
      preHeaderPanelHeight: 40,
      showCustomFooter: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      // you could debounce/throttle the input text filter if you have lots of data
      // filterTypingDebounce: 250,
      enableSorting: true,
      exportOptions: {
        sanitizeDataExport: true
      },
      gridMenu: {
        onCommand: (e, args) => {
          if (args.command === 'toggle-preheader') {
            // in addition to the grid menu pre-header toggling (internally), we will also clear grouping
            this.clearGrouping();
          }
        },
      },
      draggableGrouping: {
        dropPlaceHolderText: 'Drop a column header here to group by the column',
        // groupIconCssClass: 'fa fa-outdent',
        deleteIconCssClass: 'fa fa-times',
        onGroupChanged: (e, args) => this.onGroupChanged(args),
        onExtensionRegistered: (extension) => this.draggableGroupingPlugin = extension,
      },
      enableTextExport: true,
      enableExcelExport: true,
      excelExportOptions: { sanitizeDataExport: true },
      textExportOptions: { sanitizeDataExport: true },
      registerExternalResources: [this.excelExportService, this.textExportService],
    };

    this.columnDefinitions0 = [
      {
        id: 'title0', name: 'Task Title', field: 'title',
        width: 70, minWidth: 50,
        cssClass: 'cell-title',
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'title',
          formatter: (g) => `Title: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'duration0', name: 'Task Duration', field: 'duration',
        width: 70,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.slider, operator: '>=' },
        type: FieldType.number,
        groupTotalsFormatter: GroupTotalFormatters.sumTotals,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'duration',
          formatter: (g) => `Duration: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          comparer: (a, b) => {
            return this.durationOrderByCount ? (a.count - b.count) : SortComparers.numeric(a.value, b.value, SortDirectionNumber.asc);
          },
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'percentComplete0', name: 'Task % Complete', field: 'percentComplete',
        minWidth: 70, width: 90,
        formatter: Formatters.percentCompleteBar,
        type: FieldType.number,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.compoundSlider },
        sortable: true,
        groupTotalsFormatter: GroupTotalFormatters.avgTotalsPercentage,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'percentComplete',
          formatter: (g) => `% Complete: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        },
        params: { groupFormatterPrefix: '<i>Avg</i>: ' }
      },
      {
        id: 'start0', name: 'Task Start', field: 'start', minWidth: 60,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.compoundDate },
        formatter: Formatters.dateIso,
        type: FieldType.dateUtc,
        outputType: FieldType.dateIso,
        exportWithFormatter: true,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'start',
          formatter: (g) => `Start: ${g.value}  <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'finish0', name: 'Task Finish', field: 'finish',
        minWidth: 60,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.compoundDate },
        formatter: Formatters.dateIso,
        type: FieldType.dateUtc,
        outputType: FieldType.dateIso,
        exportWithFormatter: true,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'finish',
          formatter: (g) => `Finish: ${g.value} <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: false,
          collapsed: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'cost0', name: 'Task Cost', field: 'cost',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: { model: Filters.compoundInput },
        formatter: Formatters.dollar,
        groupTotalsFormatter: GroupTotalFormatters.sumTotalsDollar,
        type: FieldType.number,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'cost',
          formatter: (g) => `Cost: ${g.value} <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          aggregateCollapsed: true,
          collapsed: true
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'effortDriven0', name: 'Task Effort-Driven', field: 'effortDriven',
        width: 80, minWidth: 20, maxWidth: 100,
        cssClass: 'cell-effort-driven',
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filter: {
          collection: [{ value: '', label: '' }, { value: true, label: 'True' }, { value: false, label: 'False' }],
          model: Filters.singleSelect
        },
        formatter: Formatters.checkmark,
        grouping: {
          getter: 'effortDriven',
          formatter: (g) => `Effort-Driven: ${g.value ? 'True' : 'False'} <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
          aggregators: [
            new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
          ],
          collapsed: false
        }
      }
    ];

    this.gridOptions0 = {
      autoResize: {
        container: '#demo-container',
        rightPadding: 10
      },
      enableDraggableGrouping: true,
      createPreHeaderPanel: true,
      showPreHeaderPanel: true,
      preHeaderPanelHeight: 40,
      showCustomFooter: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      // you could debounce/throttle the input text filter if you have lots of data
      // filterTypingDebounce: 250,
      enableSorting: true,
      exportOptions: {
        sanitizeDataExport: true
      },
      gridMenu: {
        onCommand: (e, args) => {
          if (args.command === 'toggle-preheader') {
            // in addition to the grid menu pre-header toggling (internally), we will also clear grouping
            this.clearGrouping();
          }
        },
      },
      draggableGrouping: {
        dropPlaceHolderText: 'Drop a column header here to group by the column',
        // groupIconCssClass: 'fa fa-outdent',
        deleteIconCssClass: 'fa fa-times',
        onGroupChanged: (e, args) => this.onGroupChanged(args),
        onExtensionRegistered: (extension) => this.draggableGroupingPlugin = extension,
      },
      enableTextExport: true,
      enableExcelExport: true,
      excelExportOptions: { sanitizeDataExport: true },
      textExportOptions: { sanitizeDataExport: true },
      registerExternalResources: [this.excelExportService, this.textExportService],
    };

    this.loadData(500);
  }

  loadData(rowCount: number) {
    // mock a dataset
    this.dataset = [];
    this.dataset0 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      const randomYear = 2000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      const randomMonth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
      const randomDay = Math.floor((Math.random() * 29));
      const randomPercent = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

      this.dataset[i] = {
        id: 'id_' + i,
        num: i,
        title: 'Task ' + i,
        duration: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '',
        percentComplete: randomPercent,
        percentCompleteNumber: randomPercent,
        start: new Date(randomYear, randomMonth, randomDay),
        finish: new Date(randomYear, (randomMonth + 1), randomDay),
        cost: (i % 33 === 0) ? null : Math.round(Math.random() * 10000) / 100,
        effortDriven: (i % 5 === 0)
      };
      this.dataset0[i] = {
        id: 'id_' + i,
        num: i,
        title: 'Task ' + i,
        duration: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '',
        percentComplete: randomPercent,
        percentCompleteNumber: randomPercent,
        start: new Date(randomYear, randomMonth, randomDay),
        finish: new Date(randomYear, (randomMonth + 1), randomDay),
        cost: (i % 33 === 0) ? null : Math.round(Math.random() * 10000) / 100,
        effortDriven: (i % 5 === 0)
      };
    }
  }

  clearGroupsAndSelects() {
    this.clearGroupingSelects();
    this.clearGrouping();
  }

  clearGrouping() {
    if (this.draggableGroupingPlugin && this.draggableGroupingPlugin.setDroppedGroups) {
      this.draggableGroupingPlugin.clearDroppedGroups();
    }
    this.gridObj.invalidate(); // invalidate all rows and re-render
  }

  clearGroupingSelects() {
    this.selectedGroupingFields.forEach((g, i) => this.selectedGroupingFields[i] = '');
  }

  collapseAllGroups() {
    this.dataviewObj.collapseAllGroups();
  }

  expandAllGroups() {
    this.dataviewObj.expandAllGroups();
  }

  exportToExcel() {
    this.excelExportService.exportToExcel({
      filename: 'Export',
      format: FileType.xlsx
    });
  }

  exportToCsv(type = 'csv') {
    this.textExportService.exportToFile({
      delimiter: (type === 'csv') ? DelimiterType.comma : DelimiterType.tab,
      filename: 'myExport',
      format: (type === 'csv') ? FileType.csv : FileType.txt
    });
  }

  groupByDuration() {
    this.clearGrouping();
    if (this.draggableGroupingPlugin && this.draggableGroupingPlugin.setDroppedGroups) {
      this.showPreHeader();
      this.draggableGroupingPlugin.setDroppedGroups('duration');
      this.gridObj.invalidate(); // invalidate all rows and re-render
    }
  }

  groupByDurationOrderByCount(sortedByCount = false) {
    this.durationOrderByCount = sortedByCount;
    this.clearGrouping();
    this.groupByDuration();

    // you need to manually add the sort icon(s) in UI
    const sortColumns = sortedByCount ? [] : [{ columnId: 'duration', sortAsc: true }];
    this.angularGrid.filterService.setSortColumnIcons(sortColumns);
  }

  groupByDurationEffortDriven() {
    this.clearGrouping();
    if (this.draggableGroupingPlugin && this.draggableGroupingPlugin.setDroppedGroups) {
      this.showPreHeader();
      this.draggableGroupingPlugin.setDroppedGroups(['duration', 'effortDriven']);
      this.gridObj.invalidate(); // invalidate all rows and re-render
    }
  }

  groupByFieldName(fieldName: string, index: number) {
    this.clearGrouping();
    if (this.draggableGroupingPlugin && this.draggableGroupingPlugin.setDroppedGroups) {
      // get the field names from Group By select(s) dropdown, but filter out any empty fields
      const groupedFields = this.selectedGroupingFields.filter((g) => g !== '');

      this.showPreHeader();
      this.draggableGroupingPlugin.setDroppedGroups(groupedFields);
      this.gridObj.invalidate(); // invalidate all rows and re-render
    }
  }

  onGroupChanged(change: { caller?: string; groupColumns: Grouping[] }) {
    // the "caller" property might not be in the SlickGrid core lib yet, reference PR https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/303
    const caller = change && change.caller || [];
    const groups = change && change.groupColumns || [];

    if (Array.isArray(this.selectedGroupingFields) && Array.isArray(groups) && groups.length > 0) {
      // update all Group By select dropdown
      this.selectedGroupingFields.forEach((g, i) => this.selectedGroupingFields[i] = groups[i] && groups[i].getter || '');
    } else if (groups.length === 0 && caller === 'remove-group') {
      this.clearGroupingSelects();
    }
  }

  showPreHeader() {
    this.gridObj.setPreHeaderPanelVisibility(true);
  }

  selectTrackByFn(index: number, item: any) {
    return index;
  }

  setFiltersDynamically() {
    // we can Set Filters Dynamically (or different filters) afterward through the FilterService
    this.angularGrid.filterService.updateFilters([
      { columnId: 'percentComplete', operator: '>=', searchTerms: ['55'] },
      { columnId: 'cost', operator: '<', searchTerms: ['80'] },
    ]);
  }

  setSortingDynamically() {
    this.angularGrid.sortService.updateSorting([
      // orders matter, whichever is first in array will be the first sorted column
      { columnId: 'percentComplete', direction: 'ASC' },
    ]);
  }

  toggleDraggableGroupingRow() {
    this.clearGrouping();
    this.gridObj.setPreHeaderPanelVisibility(!this.gridObj.getOptions().showPreHeaderPanel);
  }

  enableFlag(){
    this.hideSlickgrid = !this.hideSlickgrid;
  }
}
```

Software versions:

- Angular: 13.3.9
- Angular-Slickgrid: 4.3.1
- slickgrid-universal: 1.4.0
- TypeScript: 4.6.4
- Operating System: Windows 11
- Node: 14.18.3
- NPM: 6.14.8

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid

I never used this plugin with 2 grids in the same page and wasn't aware of this issue. However, by looking at the `SlickDraggableGrouping` implementation, it looks like that was a bug that I recently fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/commit/962a756fb17476221867c977752e28bd1d74f6db#diff-85fdb9d6452b0c023072767a4f8189fc3cf6b9f3d93cf761bebac1f029fbea75) with the following changes

the previous code (used in 4.x) was removing all grids preheaders (oops sorry)

```js
dispose() {
   // ...
   emptyElement(document.querySelector('.slick-preheader-panel'));
}
```

was recently changed, and fixed the issue you're having, to target only the grid being destroyed/disposed

```js
dispose() {
   // ...
   emptyElement(document.querySelector(`.${this.gridUid} .slick-preheader-panel`));
}
```

So the original code was removing the preheader in the entire DOM tree regardless of the grid which is the bug you're having.

There's only one true solution to your problem, you'll need to upgrade to the latest Angular-Slickgrid 5.x version which has the fix. I unfortunately do not provide support for older versions of the lib, that is too much work for a single person (me) since the lib is a free Open Source project and I don't get any money from this work (apart from the very rare ko-fi contributions). The other benefit that you'll get from the upgrade is a recent small feature to provide sorting on each group by element (see below)

Or actually a possible patch, but less ideal, would be to hide the second grid (with `*ngShow` instead of `*ngIf`) instead of destroying it but that would have the side effect of keeping both grids html code in place if you can live with that.

[image]